# pass HttpServletRequest in a hasPermission expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my spring security config I've got the following settings:

```
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
      {
          http
        .authorizeRequests()  
            .antMatchers("/login.htm", "/signup.htm").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/page1.htm", "/page2.htm", "/page3.htm").access("@permission.hasPermission(principal.username))
    ....
    }
```

The @permission which contains the method hasPermission is a @Component bean which decides whether the principal username has an access to the pages. In the bean I use my dao methods to determine this. However, I need more knowledge to make the decision because it's not a single page. For instance, is there any way to know what page the user has requested and pass that in the hasPermission method? In other words, I want to do something like:

```
 .antMatchers("/page1.htm", "/page2.htm", "/page3.htm").access("@permission.hasPermission(principal.username, HttpServletRequest http))
```

See the 2nd parameter of the method. It's the http request which is the requested page so I will know whether the user requested page1, page2 or page3..
Or if I cannot pass that as a parameter how can I get the current requested page in my implementation of the hasPermission method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it using the following:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()  
            .antMatchers("/login.htm", "/signup.htm").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/page1.htm", "/page2.htm", "/page3.htm").access("@permission.hasPermission(principal.username,request))
....
}
```

This is due to the fact that the [WebSecurityExpressionRoot.request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.7.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebSecurityExpressionRoot.java#L18) property is exposed as a public final variable